# How to set opacity on Text Fields in c# Windows Form?

Tags: c#

Im working on a minimal log in form in C# and thought a little transparency in the text boxes of username and password will give it an satisfactory look. But I couldn't find any options in the property box where it would set such a thing.

Comment: Unfortunately Winform Text Boxes does not (by default) support any form of transparency or background image. I recommend using WPF controls for applications with higher appearance requirement as they are way more flexible on this.

Comment: Textbox is a legacy control and will not support any kind of glitz.